# Elman RNN with keras

Tags: keras, rnn, forecasting

I have to perform multi-step multivariate forecasting of time series, using keras. I found an example where LSTM is used. I could modify that example replacing LSTM with SimpleRNN.
Now I would like to use Elman RNN, which is different from SimpleRNN, as far as I know. How could I implement Elman RNN using keras?

I try to be more explicit, illustrating in detail what I would like to do.

I have three sequences, two of them representing the input, one the output:

```
in_seq1 = array([10, 20, 30, 40, 50, 60, 70, 80, 90])
in_seq2 = array([15, 25, 35, 45, 55, 65, 75, 85, 95])
out_seq = array([in_seq1[i]+in_seq2[i] for i in range(len(in_seq1))])
```

The sequences are used to fill the data structures X and y such that the following loop:

```
for i in range(len(X)):
print(X[i], y[i])
```

gives:

```
[[10 15]
[20 25]
[30 35]] [65 85]
[[20 25]
[30 35]
[40 45]] [ 85 105]
...
```

This means that I associate the values of X related to 3 time steps, to the values of y related to 2 time steps.

```
n_steps_in, n_steps_out = 3, 2
```

The Elman model I am trying is:

```
model = Sequential()
model.add(SimpleRNN(100, activation='relu', return_sequences=True, 
input_shape=(n_steps_in, n_features)))
model.add(TimeDistributed(Dense(n_steps_out, activation='relu')))
model.summary()
model.compile(optimizer='adam', loss='mse')
# fit model
model.fit(X, y, epochs=200, batch_size=n_steps_in, verbose=0)
```

where

```
n_features = X.shape[2]   # i.e., 2
```

Now, when I test the prediction with

```
x_input = array([[70, 75], [80, 85], [90, 95]])
x_input = x_input.reshape((1, n_steps_in, n_features))
yhat = model.predict(x_input, verbose=0)
print(yhat)
```

I get results like:

```
[[[195.89265 224.1713 ]
[162.78471 194.95282]
[139.1635  161.6026 ]]]
```

but also like:

```
[[[207.80466   0.     ]
[189.1255    0.     ]
[184.61163   0.     ]]]
```

or like:

```
[[[  0.      240.88077]
[  0.      218.17479]
[  0.      205.80429]]]
```

I would like to understand why sometimes there are 0. values in yhat (i.e., the predicted y) and why yhat has 6 values (3 pairs) instead of 2 (1 pair).

Comment: This may be helpful: https://github.com/mesnilgr/is13/blob/master/examples/elman-keras.py

Comment: Thank you. I updated my question with code that illustrates the issues I am currently facing.